# application.loadlevel not working

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

I am having trouble using the `Application.LoadLevel` from inside an if statement

Here is the code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Ritch: MonoBehaviour {


public bool dragging = false;

void Update () {

    if (PreRitch.Deathritch == true)
    {

        transform.position = new Vector3(8f,6.89f,9f);

    }

    if (transform.position.x > 11.5 && dragging == false)
    {

        Application.LoadLevel(0);

    }

    else if (transform.position.x < 4.5 && dragging == false)
    {

        Application.LoadLevel(0);

    }



}

void OnMouseDown()
{

    dragging = true;

}

void OnMouseUp()
{

    dragging = false;

}
}
```

The program is not loading the required level and if I put a print statement inside of one of the if statements nothing is printed.

Comment: Probably your `if` statement expression is false?

Comment: I put a print statement and it comes out true

Comment: You said `if I put a print statement inside of one of the if statements nothing is printed.`

Comment: I put the print statement in void update not in the if statements

Comment: You must be sure that your boolean expressions can become true, and that you added your level to build settings

Answer (score 0):

Try to change code to:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Ritch: MonoBehaviour {


public bool dragging = false;

void Update () {

    if (PreRitch.Deathritch == true)
    {

        transform.position = new Vector3(8f,6.89f,9f);

    }

    //if (transform.position.x > 11.5 && dragging == false)
    if (transform.position.x > 11.5f && dragging == false)
    {
        //Application.LoadLevel(0);
        UnityEngine.SceneManagement.SceneManager.LoadScene(0);

    }
    //else if (transform.position.x < 4.5 && dragging == false)
    else if (transform.position.x < 4.5f && dragging == false)
    {
        //Application.LoadLevel(0);
        UnityEngine.SceneManagement.SceneManager.LoadScene(0);

    }



}

void OnMouseDown()
{

    dragging = true;

}

void OnMouseUp()
{

    dragging = false;

}
}
```

You can use floats instead of doubles by adding f or F char